# Destination Host Unreachable while communicating between container using consul in docker overlay network

Tags: docker, consul, docker-network

I am using docker 17.03 version in centos 7

Kernel version - **3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64**

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I have node-0 and node-1 for the docker multi host networking and i am using consul. In node-0 i have created a consul container using the below command,

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 -h consul --name consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

then i have created a drop-in file inside /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and added the below lines,

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --cluster-store=consul://<NODE-0-PRIVATE-IP>:8500/network --cluster-advertise=<NODE0-IP>:2375"
```

once this is done, i have restarted the docker demon and created a overlay network using the command,
**docker network create -d overlay --subnet=10.10.10.0/24 my-net**
then i have created a container called container1 in node-0 and mapped it to the my-net.

In node-1 machine, i have created a drop-in file inside /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and added the below lines,

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --cluster-store=consul://<NODE-0-PRIVATE-IP>:8500/network --cluster-advertise=<NODE1-IP>:2375"
```

and started a container called container2 and mapped it to my-net.

My setup will look like,

```
node0 - consul, container1
node1 - container2
```

Inside the container2, i am trying to ping container1 but getting the below response,

```
PING container1 (10.10.10.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From container2 (10.10.10.4) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From container2 (10.10.10.4) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From container2 (10.10.10.4) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From container2 (10.10.10.4) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

from node0, `ip a` shows

```
 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:50:56:9d:9c:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet <NODE0-PRIVATE-IP>/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global ens32
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9d:9c9f/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
        link/ether 02:42:57:6d:e8:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::42:57ff:fe6d:e8a9/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    4: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
        link/ether 02:42:10:5b:7d:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.19.0.1/16 scope global docker_gwbridge
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::42:10ff:fe5b:7db5/64 scope link
```

inside container1, `ip a` shows as,

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: eth0@if19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:0a:0a:0a:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.10.3/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:aff:fe0a:a03/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
20: eth1@if21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 172.19.0.3/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe13:3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Do i need to change anything to get this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ports have you opened on any firewall between the two hosts? Please include the docker run commands for your container1/2. What does `docker network inspect my-net` output on each of the nodes?

Answer (score -1):

I have docker 18.09.1 on CentOS7, i was not able to ping a remote host from docker host machine, when pinging I was getting the IP of docker_gwbridge, network, configured by docker
searched and found this article https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2345, ran the command below and was able to ping the remote host.

```
docker network rm docker_gwbridge
```

Maybe try to leave the swarm and try,

```
docker swarm leave -f
```

Comment: Gwbridge is for requests going outside of the docker network. OP is trying to communicate between two nodes of an overlay network implemented without swarm mode.

Comment: Per your edit: as mentioned in my comment, OP is not using swarm mode. I'm not even sure it existed when the question was asked, but swarm mode is not compatible with other overlay networking key/value stores like consul. So leaving the swarm will not work.